# TYPO3 insert plugin on every new page of specific type

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x

I have created my TYPO3 extension and now I can create pages of a new type.
Now I want to have a plugin on every new page of this type. So that there will be no need to add manually a plugin on every page.
Can I do it somehow?

Answer (score 2):

You can add to your fluid template a typoscript object

```
<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.foo" />
```

Assuming that your plugin is a content object with known ID, created inside a sysfolder (just for example), the TypoScript to access it should be IIRC

```
lib.foo = RECORDS
lib.foo {
   dontCheckPid = 1
   tables = tt_content
   source = ID # Enter the object's ID here
}
```

Comment: Or more generally, if a registered plugin 'myextension_pi1' exists
<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="tt_content.list.20.myextension_pi1" />

Comment: you also can use a special column on pages of this type where you insert the plugin in a top page and inherit (`slide`) it's content to every subpage, rendered only on pages of your type.

Comment: While the answer (and solutions in comments) often will solve the issue, they do not answer the original question really.
Think of that: if you create a new page of some type, you want a CE record to be generated automatically. The editor will then be able to customise settings of e.g. the plugin, according to the needs of that new page. (e.g. only records of some category, folder or the like).
And to be honest, I think this is not easily possible with TYPO3 ATM. Maybe there is some hook or signalslot for "new page record created".